# Consulting about Loop (whit time condition) in Shell Scriptong

Tags: shell, for-loop, time, scripting, conditional-statements

I am working whit a program named "polynom" in linux shell . I have to execute this program thousand times, the program takes around 10 mins give the output file. Every time that i execute the program, i have to increase the value of a attribute in +1, so i tried to make a script to do it automatically, but it does not do what i want, so i would like to ask you, what am i doing wrong? Here is an example of the program, first running goes like this

```
miguel@miguel-OEM:~$ polynom "serie_24_28_marzo_open_5min.dat" -l1400 -m5 -d1 -p9 -L28 -opredicted_serie_24_28_marzo_open_5min_p9_incorp5_delay1.dat -V1
```

The second

```
miguel@miguel-OEM:~$ polynom "serie_24_28_marzo_open_5min.dat" -l1400 -m5 -d2 -p9 -L28 -opredicted_serie_24_28_marzo_open_5min_p9_incorp5_delay2.dat -V1
```

The third

```
miguel@miguel-OEM:~$ polynom "serie_24_28_marzo_open_5min.dat" -l1400 -m5 -d3 -p9 -L28 -opredicted_serie_24_28_marzo_open_5min_p9_incorp5_delay3.dat -V1
```

And so on... As you can see, the only difference is increase +1 to "-d" and "...delay.dat"

Now, this is the script i did to try automate the task

```
#!/bin/bash

declare -i n=1

for n in {1..1400}
do

polynom "serie_EURUSD_24_28_marzo_open_5min.dat" -l1400 -m5 -d$n -p9 -L28 \
-opredicted_serie_EURUSD_24_28_marzo_open_5min_p9_incorp5_delay$n.dat -V1 ;

sleep 10m

done
```

What did i get?

The first running is ok, but the second goes like this

```
polynom "serie_EURUSD_24_28_marzo_open_5min.dat" -l1400 -m5 -d$n -p9 -L28 -opredicted_serie_EURUSD_24_28_marzo_open_5min_p9_incorp5_delay$n.dat -V1
```

Here is the problem, it's not assingning the value "-d2" and "...delay2.dat". I hope i explained well, thx in advance.

Comment: Your script seems to have no problem and works as you expected at least in my bash. Which version of `bash` are you using?, and what happens if you use `echo polynom ...` instead of `polynom ...` and comment out `sleep 10m`.

Comment: miguel@miguel-OEM:~$ bash --version
GNU bash, versión 4.2.25(1)-release (i686-pc-linux-gnu)
Copyright (C) 2011 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
Licencia GPLv3+: GPL de GNU versión 3 o posterior <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>

Esto es software libre; usted es libre de cambiarlo y redistribuirlo.
NO hay GARANTÍA, a la extensión permitida por la ley.

Comment: This is weird, it's works perfectly whit echo, but doesnt whit "polynom"

Answer (score 0):

Try this, change from

```
polynom "serie_EURUSD_24_28_marzo_open_5min.dat" -l1400 -m5 -d$n -p9 -L28 \
-opredicted_serie_EURUSD_24_28_marzo_open_5min_p9_incorp5_delay$n.dat -V1 ;
```

to

```
polynom "serie_EURUSD_24_28_marzo_open_5min.dat" -l1400 -m5 -d"$n" -p9 -L28 \
-opredicted_serie_EURUSD_24_28_marzo_open_5min_p9_incorp5_delay"$n".dat -V1 ;
```

Comment: what can i say? I can only laugh with programming issues, two days without sleep for a couple of "" hahaha: D thx BMW, it worked perfectly, i had to use -d"$n" and same for delay. Now, shuold i close this post or something?

Comment: Good news, you need vote it up if it gives help, or accept is, if it solved your problem.

Comment: it is on the left top of my answer. Maybe you can't see them is, your reputation is too low?

Comment: yea i cant see it, my reputation says "6", is it too low?